# Script to convert time into String?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a `time(0)` column in a SQL Server database table, and I wish to create a new column using the same amount in `time(0)` but converted in number of minutes (`varchar`) (the time column gives specific durations)

I have tried the following commands in the formula section (in SQL Server Management Studio)

```
(CONVERT([varchar](10),[Duration],(10)))
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: If you have a **number** of minutes - ***why*** are you storing that as a `varchar` ?? If it's a number (looks like a number, quacks like a number) - store it as a **number**! (use `int` or `decimal(p,s)` - as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a new column that stores the number of minutes, **use an `INT`!** After all, the **number** of minutes is a numerical value.....

You can do this with a change script very easily:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD TimeInMinutes AS DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, YourTimeColumnHere) PERSISTED
```

or you might be able to do it in the visual designer, too, by just adding the formula:

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, YourTimeColumnHere)
```

Try to make sure to make this a **persistent** column so it's only calculated and updated when the time column changes - not every time to access it....

Answer (score 0):

use `datediff(mi, '00:00:00', <your time>)`:

see **<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6172/1)</kbd>**